# Android Action buttons are not appearing on action bar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-actionbar

I've been trying to add a search button to the action bar in my app, but nothing appears in the action bar other than the title in Android Studio's design window:

[image: Example]

HomeActivity.java:

```
public class HomeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

menu_home.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

activity_home.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">
    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried changing `app:showAsAction` to `android:showAsAction`, but nothing seemed to change.

Comment: Does it show up when you run the app?

Comment: @DanielNugent: Oh, I tried running the app, and the button showed up. I guess it only works in the actual app, and not in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

The preview shows exactly what is in your layout, not anything added programatically. If you want to preview the menu in design view, you need to tell Android Studio to render it:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:menu="menu_home"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, nothing changed in the design window.